# beautiful soup .find can't find anything

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to **scrape** posts in a Facebook group:

```py
URL = 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/110354088989367/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'
}


def checkSubletGroup():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    posts = soup.find_all("div", {"class_": "text_exposed_root"})
    print(soup.prettify())
    for post in posts:
        print(post)


checkSubletGroup()
```

The `div` with `class="text_exposed_root"` is clearly there because I can find it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> when I search in `print(soup.prettify())`, but when I do `soup.find_all("div", {"class_": "text_exposed_root"})` it is returning an empty list, so are many other class names that are clearly there.

Please help.

Comment: You only need to use `class_` when it's a keyword argument, not in a dictionary.

Comment: Just found the problem: all those `<div>` are commented out in the source-code of that page. I guess `bs4` ignores those tags so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all those `<div>` are inside a commented out HTML block.

Something like this can workaround the issue:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''), 'html.parser')
```

After that you can simply do:

```py
posts = soup.find_all('div', 'text_exposed_root')
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `class_` when you're checking the class using a keyword argument, because `class` is a Python reserved word and can't be used as a variable. If you pass the attributes as a dictionary, you just use `class`.

So it should be

```
posts = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "text_exposed_root"})
```

or

```
posts = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "text_exposed_root")
```

Comment: None of those options seems to have effect. I've tried both myself and they return an empty list despite those `div` being in the soup.

Comment: also tried this..either way is valid but don't work in this case...think @accdias has the right idea