# Why does Beautifulsoup.find() not give the specific result?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have this code below, and I am trying to get **'Oswestry, England'** as the result.

```
label = soup.findall('span',{'class':"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})
print(label)
```

But, it doesn't give me a value.

Here is what the **HMTL** code looks like

```
<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir" dir="ltr">
     <a data-place-id="5b756a1991aa8648" href="/search?q=place%3A5b756a1991aa8648">Oswestry, England</a>
     </span>
```

When I print label the result is the HTML code I posted above.
​
**Here is my full code:**

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

usernames = #list of username

location_list = []

for x in usernames:
    url= "https://twitter.com/" + x
    try:
        html = req.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to")
        continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
    try:
        label = soup.find('span',{'class':"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})
        label_formatted = label.string.lstrip()
        label_formatted = label_formatted.rstrip()
        if label_formatted != "":
            location_list.append(label_formatted)
            print(x + ' : ' + label_formatted) 
        else:
            print('Not found')
    except:
        print('Not found')
```

Comment: Which parser you are using to parse the HTML content?

Comment: html.parser. Tried lxml but didnt work as well

Comment: Did you check if you are using the right method for soup.*?

Comment: Use `.text` to print the text

Comment: The code works for most page with HTML that looks like this:

<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir" dir="ltr"> Oswestry, England

But, if the HTML code looks like this
<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir" dir="ltr"> <a data-place-id="5b756a1991aa8648" href="/search?q=place%3A5b756a1991aa8648">Oswestry, England</a> </span>

I can no longer get Oswestry England.

Comment: There's no `findall`, it's `find_all`.

Comment: I think you should target the 'a' tag via 'id' attribute instead.

Comment: I looked at the HTML of several twitter accounts, didn't see the class `ProfileHeaderCard-locationText` in any of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [beautiful soup .find can't find anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587283/beautiful-soup-find-cant-find-anything)

Answer (score 1):

You should call `find`, not `find_all` to get a single element. Then use the `.text` attribute to get the text content.

```
label = soup.find('span',{'class':"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})
print(label.text)
```

Comment: This also does not work.  Because the HTML of the website looks like this [<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir" dir="ltr">
 <a data-place-id="5b756a1991aa8648" href="/search?q=place%3A5b756a1991aa8648">Oswestry, England</a>
 </span>]

Comment: The HTML isn't inside `<html>` and `<body>`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you were searching for a span tag with the class attribute exactly matching your query class.  As the span has two classes, your test failed and no results returned.

Using [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp.), you could try your solution as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
soup = BS('''<span class="ProfileHeaderCard-locationText u-dir">.....</span>''', 'html.parser')
soup.select('span.ProfileHeaderCard-locationText')
```

returns span tags that contain your prescribed class.

[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38033910/13274830)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same problem, I was able to do get the innerdata from the html code by just doing this:

`label2 = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"ProfileHeaderCard-locationText"})[0].get_text`()